# Problem with Delphi android app and talkback

Tags: android, delphi, accessibility, talkback

I have an issue when trying to publish my app on the Google Play Store. The automated tests can't focus the buttons created in the app in the accessibility tests. In tests with talkback on an Android cell phone, the problem occurred too.

Even with a simple app with just two tbuttons, the focus always stays in the form, and when you click twice on the screen, the event in only one of the buttons is executed.

Comment: What buttons are you using?  `TButton`?  `TSpeedButton`?

Comment: I am using TButtons. I am trying to make the app as simple as I can.

Comment: If you have *a simple app with just two tbuttons*, you should be able to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue here in your question.